# How come some apps don't show-up on my phone's Android app market?

Tags: google-play-store

Fxcamera is a popular app, but it's not showing in my xperia x10 mini's app market search. I tried:

1. fx
2. camera
3. ymst
4. fxcamera

None gives the result. In fact, after that I've tried many apps which are listed on the internet market site http://www.android.com/market/ but not on the market app.

I live in India, is that why the apps don't show up? Is there a way to install the apps download them directly or something? Is it related to my carrier or mobile network provider?

Comment: Do you see it if you search on http://www.appbrain.com/ ?

Comment: yes I see it on appbrain.com, but the link there redirects me to the app market, which says "There are no matches in Android Market for the search: pname:ymst.android.fxcamera"

Answer (score 11):

It could be because of a few reasons:

- The app is a paid app and your country does not support purchasing paid apps (I don't know if India can or not yet?)
- Your phone does not meet the min SDK requirements of the app.  For instance, the app may require 2.1+ features, but your phone is running Android 1.5 or 1.6
- Your phone is missing a feature that the app requires in order to use it (things like SD cards, trackballs, etc.)
- The app is carrier limited (Skype was an example of this)
- Market bug.  Occasionally there are listing problems in the market, especially if an app was recently updated

Comment: There've also been cases when some apps have been missing after installing a newly released OS update. Some apps seem to require that the OS version for that device is registered with Google somehow, and that seems to take a while sometimes (Angry Birds was one of these).

Comment: It could also be that the app is no longer available in the app store. I've had that happen to a couple apps I liked and used. (Darn copyrights!) They at least stayed on my device (until I did a factory reset).

Answer (score 1):

It happens the same to me... And for such popular apps as [WeatherBug](http://www.appbrain.com/app/weatherbug/com.aws.android), which is supposed to work with "all android versions", according to them. I'm running ecclair (2.1 update 1) of the same device (xperia x10 mini). I couldn't find the [WordReference](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wordreference-com-dictionaries/com.wordreference) app either, which I don't think requires too many features.

So, according to Bryan's answer, and for these specific cases, I would point to...

> - Your phone is missing a feature that
>     the app requires in order to use it
>     (things like SD cards, trackballs,
>     etc.)
> - Market bug. Occasionally there
>     are listing problems in the market,
>     especially if an app was recently
>     updated

But, what can of special feaure can require a dictionary? Could it be becuase of the littlescreen size?

Answer (score 0):

1. Pl check your Gmail account with which you logged into Market site is the same Primary Gamil account on your phone.
2. The second reason that your phone doesn't support the listed apps.

But I am using Xperia mini Pro. I have those apps installed on my phone.